# How to configure the source file directory and install location using GNU Autotools

Tags: makefile, autotools

I want a project directory like this:

```
app/
 |
  src/
  Makefile
```

All of the .cpp and .hpp, .h files are in the `src` subdirectory. How can I configure `Makefile.am` or `configure.ac` to let the generated Makefile using the directory `/src` as the source directory? And how to let the generated executable into a specified directory like `/usr/opt`?

Another question is that If I want to make my program as a .so library, how to achieve my goal to make it install into `/usr/lib` or `/usr/local/lib`? And how to make the header files into like `/usr/local/include/app`?

Comment: what does this question have to do with c++? I'm removing this tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you just add

```
SUBDIRS = src
```

to the toplevel Makefile.am, and mention src/Makefile in AC_CONFIG_FILES.  There are some reasonable complaints about recursive make, but if all of your source is in src then the single level of recursion in make is not really an issue.  Putting the executable in /usr/opt is done by the user when setting prefix at configure time, and should not be a consideration when building the package.  To build an executable, use bin_PROGRAMS in the Makefile.am, and to build a library you should use either lib_LIBRARIES or lib_LTLIBRARIES (personally, I tend to use libtool and go with the latter.)

I think your questions about installing in /usr/lib or in /usr/opt indicate a fundamental misunderstanding.  When building the package, you absolutely do not care about that.  As the package maintainer, you indicate that the program should be installed in $(prefix)/bin (or $exec_prefix/bin, or $bindir) and that libraries should be in $libdir, but the user determines the location of $prefix and $libdir and $bindir when they run configure.  (Usually, people just set prefix, and bindir defaults to $prefix/bin while libdir defaults to $prefix/lib.)

Comment: Yep your solution is another convenient one. Thanks for your reply another question I want to ask is that how can I specify the install location of my header files? I think it will also determined by the -prefix for configure. But what to be put in my Makefile.am? I tried "nobase_include_HEADERS = foo/Header.hpp" in my Makefile, it cannot make. Can you give some hints?

Comment: What is the error?  If foo/Header.hpp exists in the source directory relative to the Makefile.am in which you have that line, it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Typically for executable files you'll have something like:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = foo
foo_SOURCES = $(top_srcdir)/src/foo_main.c \
$(top_srcdir)/src/foo_main.h \
$(top_srcdir)/src/something_else.c
```

This will install in the prefix directory's /bin directory, though which isn't what you want, but it's kind of what you users will expect.

To do what you want you'll need to do this:

```
 myexedir = $(prefix)/opt
 myexe_PROGRAMS = foo
 foo_SOURCES = ...
```

where foo_SOURCES is as above.

For libraries it's just:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libfoo.la
libfoo_la_SOURCES = ...
```

and it will install in the prefix directory's /lib directory.  Setting up where the lib installs isn't up to you (directly) but whoever invokes configure:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
```

will make the lib install (when *make install* is called) in /usr/lib

```
./configure
```

or

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
```

will make the lib install in /usr/local/lib.

Comment: Hi @ldav1s. Thanks for your reply another question I want to ask is that how can I specify the install location of my header files? I think it will also determined by the -prefix for configure. But what to be put in my Makefile.am? I tried "nobase_include_HEADERS = foo/Header.hpp" in my Makefile, it cannot make. Can you give some hints?

Answer (score 0):

Put the autoconf and automake files *configure.ac* and *Makefile.am* in the "src" directory and write in your documentation that the "./configure" command should be run there instead of in the top level directory? Otherwise you can not really avoid having at least some of the autoconf/automake files at the top level.

Comment: I disagree with you, I am sure we can "remote make". well I think we can use something like AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS=subdir-objects, the question is that if remote make, all the object files will be put into the src which is annoying, I do non't know how to specify where to put the object file and executable into another location.

Comment: Maybe I did not understand your real objective. If you want to keep the object files separate from the sources, just go to wherever you want to keep them and run /where/ever/your/sources/are/app/src/configure and it will pull the necessary files automagically from the directory where the configure script is located.

Comment: Hmm... the question in its new edited form is quite different from the original. And it is now quite many questions. I am confused.

Comment: sorry that I didn't include the whole questions altogether, now my objective is shown in the modified questions.